# SQL query to select produts using join on specific problem

Tags: mysql, database

Two tables are given. In one table we have following columns

- `productid`
- `product_title`
- `priority`
- `categoryid`

and in second table we have

- `id`
- `productid`
- `color`
- `selling_price`
- `stock`

How to write a SQL query to select all product from table having more than 2 colors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [having count with join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234081/having-count-with-join)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a sub-query to select product id from the stock table where product has multiple colors.

```
SELECT PRODUCTID FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY PRODUCTID HAVING COUNT(COLOR)>2
```

Use it in the main query

```
SELECT T1.PRODUCTID,T1.PRODUCT_TITLE FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE PRODUCTID IN 
(SELECT PRODUCTID FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY PRODUCTID HAVING COUNT(COLOR)>2)
```

I'm assuming the Database is not DB2 in which case this query won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.productid, T1.product_title,COUNT(T2.COLOR) counter
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN table2 T2 s ON  T1.productid = T2.productid
GROUP BY T1.productid, T1.product_title
HAVING COUNT(T2.COLOR) > 2;
```

Comment: This assumes (not unreasonably) that combinations are unique

Comment: This is a better approach which will work on DB2 as well.